# How to set info.plist before eas building in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, build, info.plist, eas

I am using Windows 10 and I have React Native expo project without IOS directory.
As you know, we can build IOS using eas build without IOS directory and we can download ipa file from the link.
But Now what I want to do is modify and revise some strings in the info.plist before building.

The problem is, I don't have ios directory and this file is ejected in the eas server while eas building. So I can't modify it.
Do you have any solution to modify info.plist before eas building out of ios folder?
Or are there any ways to set the content of this file in app.json or things like that?
Thank you.

What I am trying is to eject the ios folder before eas building. BUt failed.